Exponential decay curve fitting
I have an initial set of data (Column A-C), and I noticed the % Gain/Lost follows some sort of exponential decay. I've plotted it (data from A2-A13, C2-C13) and got $y=16.391e^{-2.246x}$ and $R^2=0.9781$. That's all the data that I'm working with.
Assuming the closing price will go higher, how would I fit a more accurate exponential curve to predict the future data points? I would like to predict the "highest" future closing price (which would be around 5.28), before it drops from it's peak.
The actual "future" data would be in the table in Column F-H. Basically I'm looking to derive/predict future data that would match as accurately as possible to what is shown in the table in Column F-H, given I only have data in the table in Column A-C.
Plotting data from F2-F21, H2-H21, will get $y=11.18e^{-0.972x}$ and $R^2=0.9822$. So I guess I'm also looking how I would get a more accurate equation (and A & B values), based only just from the first set of data? Basically is there a way to derive $y=11.18e^{-0.972x}$ from $y=16.391e^{-2.246x}$?

Edit: Thanks all for your comments and feedback. So is there any way to extrapolate, to get a value close or equal to 5.08, based just on data from the left table?
As mentioned I could convert one of those exponential equations into the other by scaling the $x$ and $t$ axes, but is there any way to know "how much to scale" assuming I only know $y=16.391e^{-2.246x}$?
Finally, from my understanding of regression, for $y=Ae^{Bx}$, $A$ is the constant that represents the initial amount changing/starting value before any decay occurs. Where does 16.391 come from, because how is that the starting value? And what would the difference between 16.391 and 11.18 indicate/imply?
As for the constant $B$, am I right in saying a higher $B$ means a faster rate of decay? So the decay constant of -2.246 would indicate a faster decay constant of -0.972?
Thus, if I assume that all closing prices follow a constant -0.972, is there anyway to get 5.08, just based from data in the table on the left?

The answer to the question in the last sentence is that you can convert one of those exponential equations into the other by scaling the $x$ and $t$ axes. I can't tell whether that answers the question you ask about prediction "future data". For that you would have to [edit] the question to clarify.

And you might change it to from its peak while you’re at it.

I'm pretty sure the short answer is "adding more data points always changes the output values in a regression" (the long answer being "adding more data points almost always changes the output values in a regression").  I don't know exactly how you have your spreadsheet set up there, but if you say change row 14 in your first set-up there to the new price of 5.08 you'll get something closer to your new data values but still not the same. (Of course then the question is how do you know to use $5.08 two weeks before the market hit that value.)

Thank you for all your comments, its most appreciated and helpful. Yes, I think essentially what @tabstop described, is what I'm trying to achieve. Basically, based just on the left table, is there any way to extrapolate, to potentially get a value close to 5.08? Is the only way to go about doing this, is "knowing beforehand and assuming" the closing prices would follow the equation $y=11.18e^{-0.972x}$? Or if initially the closing prices & % Gain/Lost do not fit an exponential decay well, and I can plot future closing prices for it to fit an exponential decay?

A much better fit is obtained with a shift of the ordinates. For example with the first data set :

For the second data set the above equation model is not yet sufficient to obtain a good fit. For example a linear term is added to fit better at large x and negative y.

Of course one could try other equation models for example of double exponential kind.

Thanks, may I know how you calculated the shift of ordinates? By hand or by using a software? Yeah for the 2nd table I initially used all the data except the last 2 rows which were 0% and negative.

Assuming I only have data in the first table, and thus your equation $y=-15.8 + 757.912e^{-1.486x}$, is there any possible way to extrapolate, to model the movement of the "closing price" to get something close to 5.08?

The values of the paramaters of the model equation are currently computed thanks to non-linear regression methods. Specialised softwares are commonly used. I used such a software (home made not portable). Alternatively a simpler method exists but not conventional. I don't think that the computation is the key point. The key point seems to be the modelisation. In other words the determination of the model equation and the number of adjustable parameters in the model equation.

Sorry, I cannot answer on your question about 5.08 because I have no clue how this value appears from the model equation ( That is again a question of modelisation).

Noted with thanks @JJacquelin, most appreciated. But basically for the 2 data sets, I could see the relationship between the variables are not linear, so a more complex model equation is needed. Is there a "quick way" (or a best practices used) to determine the model equation and adjustable parameters (at least in a generalised sense)? I initially guessed it follows more towards an exponential function (instead of polynomial, logarithmic functions etc.) so that's why I plotted it in Excel using exponential.

They are a lot of approaches. Two major ways are : (1) Purely mathematical ( inspection of the shape of the curve to be fitted, trying several equations, etc.). (2) Physical approach (bulding a model equation from the physical laws of the phenomenons involved in the experiment). The purely mathematical approach can give as accurate fitting as wanted by increassing the number of mathematical terms and the number of parameters. The drawback is that the model has no physical signifiance and extrapolation outside the range of fitting is highly doubtful. That is the case of my above answer.
